# How do I make good guy attacks only hit bad guys and vice versa?

Tags: collision-detection, architecture, javascript, game-mechanics, projectile-physics

My game has many different type of good guys and many different type of bad guys.  They will all be firing projectiles at each other but I don't want any accidental collateral damage to occur for either alignment.  So bad guys should not be able to hit/damage other bad guys and good guys should not be able to hit/damage other good guys.

The way I'm thinking of solving this is by making it so that the `Unit` instance (this is javascript, btw), has an `alignment` property that can be either `good` or `bad`.  And I'll only let collision happen if the

```
class Attack

    boolean didAttackCollideWithTarget(target)
        return attack.source.alignment != target.alignment and collisionDetected(attack.source, target)
```

This is pseudo-code, of course.

But I'm asking this question because I get the sense that there might be a much more elegant way to design this besides adding yet another property to my `Unit` class.

Comment: Filtering is the typical approach here. Essentially that's what you've described. There's also layers. Two layers, bad layer and good layer. Bad guys projectiles are fired into the good layer and vise versa.

Comment: @Byte56 Can you elaborate on this "layer" concept?  Or at least link to something about it?  I've never heard of that before.

Comment: Essentially they're different "worlds". All the objects in a layer interact with each other, but don't interact with any other layer. This can be done with tags (like filtering), or by totally different datasets for each layer.

Comment: In a word, it's grouping. Group good bullets and only check for collision against bad guys. Flixel has a concept like this.

Comment: One nitpicky design note: do you want 'friendly-fire' shots to _hit_ but do no damage, or do you want them to completely ignore allies, possibly passing through them to strike enemies instead?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki the latter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Collision Filtering

A more robust situation that scales into many layers is to use filtering, which is not the same thing as grouping.

This works best by giving every object 2 [bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

```
Category
Mask
```

And only trigger a collision if the below is true.

```
(filterA.maskBits & filterB.categoryBits) != 0 &&
(filterA.categoryBits & filterB.maskBits) != 0;
```

Its easiest to default the Mask to 0xFFFF which results in it colliding with everything. And default the Category to 0x0001. 
objects collide with the categories in the others mask will there be a collision.

Another way to think of it is each object has a type and a list of all the types it can collide with. Only when two objects both collide with the types of each other is there a collision. You could have the same behavior having a list of enums instead of a mask but a mask in an order of magnitude faster.

### Scenario you describe

I like to take advantage of enums in this situation.

So say we have.

```
enum Categories {
    GoodGuy =           0x0001,
    BadGuy =            0x0002,
    Bullet =            0x0004,
    GlassWall =         0x0008,
    Lazer =             0x0010,
    All =               0xFFFF
};
```

Bullet shot by a good guy

```
 Category = Bullet
 Mask = BadGuy | GlassWall
```

Good Guys

```
 Category = GoodGuy
 Mask = All
```

Bad Guys

```
 Category = BadGuy
 Mask = All
```

Which results in the below when a Bullet shot by a good guy hits another good guy.

```
(All & GoodGuy) != 0 && <-- Passes
(GoodGuy & (BadGuy | GlassWall)) != 0; <-- This would fail
```

But it will hit bad guys.

```
(All & BadGuy) != 0 && <- Passes
(BadGuy & (BadGuy | GlassWall)) != 0; <-- Passes
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining this *conceptually* instead of explaining it at a low level detail of bit arithmetic?

Comment: @tieTYT sure check again in 5 mins

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem at my current project (in Java).
After a couple tries is solved it by creating four lists.
This solution is created in Java and for a 2D Game but should also work, in a similar way, in JavaScript

```
public static main (String [] args)
{
    private List<Bullets> bullets_GoodGuys = new LinkedList <Bullet>(); //List of all bullets fired by good guys
    private List<Bullets> bullets_BadGuys  = new LinkedList <Bullet>(); //List of all bullets fired by bad guys
    private List<Guys> goodGuys  = new LinkedList <Guys>(); //List of all good guys
    private List<Guys> badGuys  = new LinkedList <Guys>();  //List of all good guys

    init();
    ...
    while(game_is_running)
    {
        ... 
        for(int i=0;i>=goodGuys.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j>=bullets_BadGuys.length;i++)
            {
                if(goodGuys.get(i).getBounding().interacts(bullets_BadGuys.get(i).getBounding()))
                {// If a good guy was hit by a bullet from a bad guy
                    goodGuys.get(i).getDamage();
                    bullets_BadGuys.remove((bullets_BadGuys.get(i));
         }   }   }
       for(...) //same for the bad guys
       {...}
}
```

pseudo-code

```
class Guys
{
   private float xkoordinate;
   private float ykoordinate;
   private BufferedImage look;
   private Rectangle bounding = new Rectangle(xkoordinate,ykoordinate,look.getWith(),look.getHight())
   ...
}
```

pseudo-code,
same for the class Bullets

This might not be the best or fastest solution but it will help you in the moment.
I’m sorry that I cannot give you a solution in JavaScript but I hope I could help you

By the way my English isn’t the best but I hope you could follow my explanation