# How to properly use fixture filter mask bits?

Tags: box2d

In the below code, I've created a mask value for the `MASK_bullet`. Which `~CATEGORY_BULLET` cannot collide with bullet, `CATEGORY_ENEMY` can collide with bullet and so on. Now the problem is, it is not behaving the way as expected.

```
public static final short CATEGORY_ENEMY = 0x0002;
public static final short CATEGORY_MAP_OBJECT = 0x0008;
public static final short CATEGORY_BULLET = 0x00032;

public static final short MASK_BULLET = ~CATEGORY_BULLET | CATEGORY_ENEMY | CATEGORY_MAP_OBJECT;
```

How I set the category and mask.

```
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = CATEGORY_BULLET;
fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = MASK_BULLET;
```

Comment: ~CATEGORY_BULLET is 0b11110111, or-ing that with CATEGORY_ENEMY (0b01000000) doesn't do anything. The ~ operator is bitwise not, i.e. change 1 to 0 and vice versa.

Comment: I wrote up a small guide for another question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/58165/8119

Comment: Potential duplicate?

Comment: I didn't vote to close because while the same answer works for both questions, the question its self is still not quite the same.

Comment: I don't think its the same @ClassicThunder

Comment: @ClassicThunder in the given `MASK_BULLET`, the bullet is colliding with another bullet. Even I set the `~`